# C+Python+Ubuntu SIGUSR1 Signal Sharing

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, signals

Finding a solution for below questions,
I used SIGUSR1 signal in my c application.for timer purpose.
i also used same signal in one of my python script.
Both are Separate application and running fine together
Right Now There is no problem at all.
 **Questions :-** 
a) is that is a proper way?..or i should have to use SIGUSR2 signal for one of them
b) What will be the effect if i provide SIGUSR1 to python script via C application?

Comment: It's not clear what your situation is. Presumably the C app and the python script are running as seperate processes. So why do you think a signal sent to one of them would in any way affect the other?

Comment: Thanks You kaylum for your reply..
Yes C application and python script are a separate applications.
As i SIGUSR signals are used for IPC so i thought that might corrupt any of two application ..So i asked about that.

Comment: SIGUSR1 by default *terminates* the process. SIGUSR1 as such does not have any meaning to CPython.